# GraphicsMagick: Pattern instead of transparent background

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, composite, graphicsmagick

With ImageMagick I can use the command below to replace a transparent background of an image with a pattern. It seems to work perfectly even with semi-transparent pixels.

```
composite -compose Dst_Over -tile pattern:checkerboard 'src_file_with_transparent_background.png' 'output_file.jpg'
```

Is there a way to do the same with GraphicsMagick?

Comment: This command to replace a transparent background with a color works for ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick:

gm convert 'src_file_with_transparent_background.png' -background HotPink -flatten 'output_file.jpg'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
gm montage -texture pattern:checkerboard -mode Concatenate input.png output.jpg
```

Many thanks to the GraphicsMagick maintainer Bob Friesenhahn for his help resolving this problem! You can find his original answer in this thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/discussion/250738/thread/9d43ab46/